# Sorting an integer field not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, columnsorting

If i click the column header named Days, i expect to sort the data according to the numeric values from the lowest number to the highest(when ascending) and the vice-versa but it is not working correctly, example when the data is 7,18,7,33,28,35,21,7,27,7,48 it sorts like 11,7,14,24,34,12,24,28,11,13,55. I have tried setting the dataformatstring to numeric value, and the query returns an integer but still not working.

```
<asp:GridView ID="rgList" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" EnableViewState="False"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="MAID"
            PageSize="50"
            DataSourceID="odsList" GridLines="None"
            OnRowCommand="rgList_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="rgList_RowDataBound"
            ShowFooter="False" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered GridViewHeader tableCompact">
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-mh"></PagerStyle>
            <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="50" HeaderText="Days" SortExpression="DayOfApproved">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDayOfApproved" Font-Size="8" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="badge badge-pill badge-danger" Text='<%# Bind("DayOfApproved")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: In odsList data source what is the dataType of the column DayOfApproved?

Comment: The datatype the method returns for the datasource is integer